# VB.net PictureBox with transparent PNG

Tags: vb.net, winforms, png, transparency, picturebox

I hope someone can help me.

I have placed a few PictureBoxes in a VB.net app in Visual Studio 2012 (Express). I've set the Picturebox BackColor to Transparent and used a PNG with alpha-transparency in the PictureBox.

My intention is to slightly overlap a few of the PictureBoxes. The problem is the PictureBoxes dont appear to be acknowledging the transparency. When the BackColor is set to transparent, it appears as if the BackColor is automatically set to that of the Form, and not to be truly transparent.

As such, when I overlap the PictureBox, the one at the top (furthest forward) doesnt let the parts of the one below it "peek through" at the transparency.

Am I doing something wrong? I even tried using a GIF image (although this wouldnt be ideal due to lack of alpha-channel support), but this did the same thing. I find it odd that this doesnt work properly when I could do this back in the VB6 days (albeit with GIF only and not PNGs), so i must be doing something wrong.

Please could someone help?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong.  Windows Forms does not have true transparency.  I don't know if there is a way to achieve what you want using Windows Forms.  You will likely have to avoid using Picture Boxes and paint the bitmaps directly in the Paint event.  Or use WPF where transparency is supported.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: Hm...not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks for clarifying...

Could you advise how one would go about "painting" the images (mostly PNGs with alpha-transparency) directly onto the form? Sorry I'm new to VB.net

Comment: I'm not real strong in Windows graphics.  In the OnPaint override of your form, you get a PaintEventArgs instance, e.  You would use `e.Graphics.DrawImage()` to draw the bitmap directly to some location on the form.  Of course you will have to load your bitmap images.  Refer to [this link](http://bobpowell.net/faqmain.aspx) for lots of information regarding graphics and windows forms.